# How should I make custom table behavior more accessible?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

My team and I are building a web-app for a customer who has requested custom functionality pertaining to data-tables: upon clicking the header of a given table column, the table then becomes sorted based on that column. This functionality is already implemented.

However, an important stipulation of the contract is compliance with WCAG 2.1 accessibility standards. Aside from within tables, we have `aria` labels in all the right places, but it's unclear how we should go about making this custom table behavior more accessible-- particularly for screen-reading tech. As of now, the table header cells themselves have event-handlers for clicks to trigger the functionality, but no semantic `<button>`s are involved in this process, which is where things start to feel a little wrong for me.

The table header cells are also focusable, so that users can use `Enter` or `Spacebar` to toggle the functionality that way. How should we handle communicating this behavior to the user, especially those using screen-readers? Since this functionality is not typical of what is otherwise a fairly standard table, guidelines and requirements from WCAG and other sources are [unclear.](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/)

I apologize, but I am unable to provide a screenshot or code snippet due to the sensitive and proprietary nature of the content.

Comment: Might be helpful to include a screenshot and some code.  First of all, how are you visually communicating to the user that the header can sort?  Seems tricky because you don't want to mix roles, but you probably need some screen reader text that will indicate the action when clicking.  The most challenging piece, to me, is if you run into any problems putting a role=button inside a table head...

Comment: In order to visually communicate that the header can sort, we use up/down arrow icons and a `pointer` cursor, not unlike the header [here.](https://datatables.net/index) I considered using a button in the header, but that raises all kinds of other questions, which then lead to the big question that is this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any table that is readonly and also is meant not to be sorted etc. standard HTML tables should be used.
In your case please use the design pattern grid from the ARIA 1.1 guideline (chapter 3.12 under this link https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#grid)
Your customer should familiarize himself about the keyboard commands ARIA declares for grids. Manipulating theese keys will mean much work to you and irritating the screen reader user and hurt WCAG.

Comment: Thank you, your link was very useful for helping me understand what requirements would be in this case. The [Data Grid Examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/grid/dataGrids.html) link located therein also went a long way.

Comment: Please do **not** use the grid pattern.  A grid should only be used if the data cells in the table can be edited (similar to how a spreadsheet works).  Being able to sort the table does not make it a grid.  It's still a basic table.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two decent examples of accessible sortable tables:

- https://assets.cms.gov/resources/framework/2.0/Pages/datatables.html
- https://adrianroselli.com/2021/04/sortable-table-columns.html

The first one is a little too wordy with it's announcement to screen readers and could be shortened up for a better user experience and the second one is a little too terse with just saying "title button".  We need a Goldilocks example between the two but both examples show how to use a `<button>` in the table header and the use of [`aria-sort`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-sort).

I didn't hear anything in your OP that would indicate that a [grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#grid) should be used.  Note that the first sentence in the grid definition says that a grid is *"a composite widget containing a collection of one or more rows with one or more cells where some or all cells in the grid are focusable by using methods of two-dimensional navigation, such as directional arrow keys."*  In other words, if the user will be able to navigate the table using the up/down/left/right arrow keys (as if you're navigating through a spreadsheet), then a grid is appropriate.  But if you have a "normal" table that does **not** allow navigating cell by cell, then a standard `<table>` can be used.  Just add buttons to your column headings (`<th>`) that allow the table to be sorted.